# MongoDB with NVMe SSD

Tags: mongodb, ssd, nvme

Does anyone have recommendations on the RAID configuration when running MongoDB on NVMe SSDs? Is the best practice still RAID10 like with HDDs and SATA SSDs?

Thanks.

Comment: Not MongoDB but we do Couchbase on Intel P3608's, we just use R0 on them, we boot from 2 x 300GB SAS disks in R1 but the data can rebuild very quickly if we lose the NVMe drive.

Answer (score 3):

Using NVMe or traditional HDD drives do not override the purposes of RAID, which is providing better IO rates than a single drive can, replication for increased data durability and larger storage capacity per logical drive.

Of course, better performant hardware like NVMe drives fixes some use cases that were traditionally solved by RAID (mainly IO and bandwith rates), but under really demanding workloads, even a single NVMe drive may not be sufficient and RAIDs of NVMe drives may still apply.

For a noSQL workload like Mongo, and in fact for any data storage use case, RAIDs of SSD drives are critical to provide high availability and durability.

Comment: I have the same question but with the emphasis on performance (not availability or durability). Is there any performance gain to be expected by Raiding multiple nvme drives together versus a single drive?

Comment: You will obtain exactly the same benefit ratio between HDD and SSD backed arrays given the same RAID configuration. The only difference will be the scale, because of the difference in the baseline performance a single disk can provide between those technologies. Should a given RAID setup provide 10x performance with HDDs, the same will still apply with SSD and NVMe drives.

Comment: Remember also that RAID performance increase is achieved through IO stripping. If your average IO size is smaller than the RAID strips you should not expect any noticeable IO or bandwidth improvement, as your workload won't be able to take advantage of the underlying RAID setup.